# Why this Angular i18n application doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

help me please to deal - translate doesn't work when i run application and click the button "german", so i have no translate this phrase to german language, here is code:

```
<html ng-app="">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgithub.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate/master/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="well">
        <h2 translate="TITLE">Hello</h2>
        <p translate="FOO">This is a paragraph</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN">english</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="changeLanguage('de')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_DE">german</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

      app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.translations('en', {
          TITLE: 'Hello',
          FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
          BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
          BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
        });
        $translateProvider.translations('de', {
          TITLE: 'Hallo',
          FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
          BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
          BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
      });

      app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
        $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
          $translate.uses(key);
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you specifically describe what doesn't work? What are expected and actual results?

Comment: when i run application and click the button "german", so i have no translate this phrase to german language

Comment: Does something happen when you click a button? Are there any errors in   JavaScript console?

Comment: No, no errors,i just click the button "german" and nothing to do, the phrase stays in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple.

You just forgot to add the `ng-app="at"` at the top of the page (as your module is called "at").

:)

Your exactly same code is working [here](http://jsbin.com/IJacuyU/1/)

Comment: @VitRasmussen accept the answer if it suits you. There must be a tick mark on the left.